# i want to give functionality to my comment submit button in laravel, i want to save comments to database, and show latest comments on view.

Tags: laravel-5

I have created a textarea and a submit button, they can be seen on the view, but not functional. I want to add comment below my post and want that comment to save in database that i have created in mysql, i have made a commentController, i am not sure what code goes in there.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\post;
use App\comment;
use Auth;

class commentController extends Controller
{
    public function index(post $post)
    {
        return response()->json($post->comments()->with('user')->latest()->get());
    }

    public function store(Request $request, post $post)
    {
        $comment = $post->comments()->create([
            'body' => $request->body,
            'user_id' => Auth::id()
        ]); 

        $comment = comment::where('id', $comment->id)->with('user')->first();

        return $comment->toJson();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have written an ajax code, i am submitting the same below, please help me in improving the code.

Comment: $('document').ready(function() { var flag=0; 
                         $('.comment').on('click',function() { var id= $(this).data("id"); 
                         $.ajax({ type:'POST', url:'/comments', data:{id:post_id,flag:user_id},

Comment: I have taken post_id, user_id, author, body as the attributes(colomns) of comments table.